# limit of sequence of integrals on [0,1]

Tags: integration

> $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$.
>
> Let $S(n)=\int_0^1x^nnf(x)dx$.
>
> What is the limit of $S(n)$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

I have tried using product rule, but I have not made any progress.

Comment: Please fix your post by using MathJax to clearly write the quantities you have.

Comment: What is "(x^n)nf"?

Comment: @AnonymousIGuess (x^n)*n*f(x)

Comment: @lioness99a I know you mean well but looking back at OP's post history, it seems that they have very rarely edited their own posts with MathJax, having other people do it for them.

Comment: @tony Okay. Try to use the fact that $f$ is continuous over the compact set $[0,1]$, which means that it is bounded there by the extreme value theorem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Honestly, it takes such a short length of time to make the change that I just do it. I would rather spend 30 seconds fixing posts than looking at hundreds of unformatted questions

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678024.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $u=x^{n+1}$

$$S_n = \int_0^1 nx^n f(x)dx=\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1 f\left(u^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)du$$

Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it must be bounded, thus we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \int_0^1 f\left(u^0\right)du = f(1)\int_0^1 du = f(1)$$

Comment: is there any solution using elementary real analysis. I have not studied measure theory

Comment: DCT may be overkill, but all you really need is uniform convergence.